# Creating Balanced Dataset Using Scikits

Tags: python, scikit-learn, class-imbalance

I have a classic `User-Item dataset` where each row (i.e., `(user, item)`) indicates the action of a user clicking/selecting an item. Now, the dataset only provides *positive samples* and does not specifically indicate whether a user has disliked an item. In order to create a *balanced dataset*, I would like to create random negative samples (for instance randomly pick a set of items which the user has never clicked). Of course, I can achieve this by writing a program; however, I found this library in python Scikits called [imbalanced-learn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imbalanced-learn#id32), which seems to provide various sampling techniques. Can someone provide a small code-snippet that can use this library (or some other python library) to achieve this?.

Comment: For an ecommerce setting, you might also look at pageviews. A pageview with click is a positive sample, and pageview without a click could be seen as negative.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to *invent* new negative samples to have a balanced dataset, because your current dataset only have positive samples.

However, the library you mentioned only re-samples a dataset where all classes are present. The *sample creation process* is by definition data-specific, as there can be impossible attribute combinations, etc.

If you want to **blindly** create combination of attribute values, you can use the stuff in module `random`:

- To create integer attributes:

  ```
  def random_integer(min_val, max_val):
      return randint.randint(0, 9))
  ```
- To create real-valued attributes:

  ```
  def random_float(min_val, max_val):
      return random.uniform(min_val, max_val)
  ```
- To create discrete attributes:

  ```
  def random_discrete(value_list):
      return random.choice(value_list)
  ```

And then, with a loop, generate your negative samples in a loop:

```
    def generate_negative_sample():
        return {'attr1': random_discrete(['a', 'b', 'c']),
                'attr2': random_float(-10., 10.),
                'attr3': random_integer(0, 4)}

    random_samples = [generate_negative_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Version**

```
# generate 2d classification dataset

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=3, n_features=2)
```

**Moons Classification Problem** (swirl like data)

```
# generate 2d classification dataset

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.1)
```

The **make_circles** generates a binary classification problem with datasets that fall into concentric circles and few more are also there.

### References

[Scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html)

[Imbalanced learn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_make_imbalance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-datasets-plot-make-imbalance-py)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it addresses my question. I don't want to generate any synthetically balanced/unbalanced dataset. I just want to modify an existing user-item dataset to "make it balanced".